# How to make sure data lines up on highcharts xAxis across 4 seperate graphs?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating 4 graphs that are linked together via zoom.  The x-axis are supposed to be the same, but for some reason the ticks are not spacing correctly once you zoom... also the red line has to be lined up exactly between the four graphs but I am assuming that the reason it wont line up is due to the ticks on the xaxis on all the graphs... any ideas as to how I could fix this?  JSFiddle at end.

Im using this type of event on the xAxis to zoom on all the graphs:

```
events: {
                        afterSetExtremes: function() {
                            if (!this.chart.options.chart.isZoomed) 
                            {
                                var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                                var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
                                var zmRange = computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);
                                chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval =zmRange;
                                chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                chart4.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;                   
                                chart4.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;


                               chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                               chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                               chart4.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                                chart4.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true)
                                chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                                 chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                                 chart4.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                               chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Here are the graphs:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNWxq/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Please take look at the example http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/33/ which looks like similar. But you need to set the same value of minrange / tickInterval for each chart.

Comment: Thank you! I did set the same minRange for each chart and every time i set same tickinterval on each chart it crashes the browser... i.e. 5... so the only way it will work currently is if i set each tickinterval to null... any thoughts on how to fix it?